# Vlookup with three comments depends on found value vba code or formula ( very hard to find solution)

Tags: vba, excel

I have very difficult scenario where i need to mention three comments by tow V lookup. let me explain you situation.

We are getting three sheets in workbook with values every weekly.

sheet1 range A1 to A5 value , lookup values sheet2 range A:B and lookup value sheet3 range A:B. yes i can able to put two V lookup , but problem is 3 comments i need to show in single output.

When i lookup values found in sheet2 need comment as "found value in sheet2" , if not it has to lookup sheet3 range if found then it has to give comment as "found value in sheet3" and if value not found need to give comment as " invalid data".

through vba can is it possible and three comments should be sheet1 in a single output based on values?

am looked in google i can use IFSA formula and apply formula but i cant provide three comments ...

For us its really hard every weekend , Please help me with VBA Code or Any formula at one shot for three comments ?

Really appreciate your help

Comment: In order for us to help you in the best way, you need to show what work - formulas or VBA - you've already tried. Then perhaps a screenshot of sample data to help explain what you want. We don't write code for you but the StackOverflow community is very happy to help you figure this out yourself.

Comment: Just nest the `IF` statements:  `=IF(first, IF(second, IF(third, T3, F3), F2), F1)`

Comment: Thank you for the reply. i tried V lookup separately two times. am looking can this be done in single with comments ?

Comment: am not getting exactly what i need to do "Just nest the IF statements: =IF(first, IF(second, IF(third, T3, F3), F2), F1) – Comintern"

Comment: tried in excel getting error " you have entered too many arguments for his function" Kindly help me on same.... two v lookup value.

Comment: (one comment here start with first lookup found means comment if not it has loop second V lookup comment if found or not found (two comments here )

Comment: IF(VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!A1:B4,2,FALSE , IF(VLOOKUP(a1,Sheet3!$A:$B,2,FALSE , "found in sheet1"),"found in sheet2","invalid data").... am getting error am sure somewhere i lost

Comment: To start with, you are missing the closing parenthesis ")" for each `VLOOKUP(,,,FALSE) ` function

Comment: =IF(VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!A1:B4,2,FALSE) , IF(VLOOKUP(a1,Sheet3!$A:$B,2,FALSE) , "found in sheet1","found in sheet2","invalid data"))

Comment: still same error i modified as required three comments at last in formula... is that correct way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually have up to 7 Nested (IF) functions in Excel - [Nested Formula Limit](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/nested.htm)

You need to make sure that you properly close each function.  This can be seen when editing the formula, it will highlight the opening/closing parentheses as you arrow through the formula.

*If it tries to select a range while using the arrow keys, hit F2 to toggle between Edit/Enter modes.*

I think you want this...

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet1!A1:B4,2,FALSE)),IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!A1:B4,2,FALSE)),IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet3!A1:B4,2,FALSE)),"Invalid Data", "Sheet 3"),"Sheet2"),"Sheet1")
```

Actually, on second thought, I assume you want whatever is in Column B

```
=IFNA(VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet1!A1:B4,2,FALSE),IFNA(VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!A1:B4,2,FALSE),IFNA(VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet3!A1:B4,2,FALSE),"Invalid Data")))
```

Comment: Its working partial tried ,,, not picking all values i checked three to four times. Thank you for the response . I do understand its not so easy formula

Comment: =IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet1!A:B,1,FALSE)),IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!A:A,1,FALSE)),IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet3!A:A,2,FALSE)),"Invalid Data", "Sheet 3"),"Sheet2"),"Sheet1")

Comment: @Basavaraj k.s. Sorry, I cut the ranges short for testing....glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need to determine if the first VLOOKUP is found, and if not, use the second VLOOKUP. Thats super simple. Assuming the formula Profex provided doesn't work:

```
=IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP("A1", Sheet2!A1:B4, 2, False), "Err")="Err",IFERROR(VLOOKUP("A1", Sheet3!A1:B4, 2, False), "Not Found"), VLOOKUP("A1", Sheet2!A1:B4, 2, False))
```

Comment: i tried your last response no working... my question my sheet1 value is base to search into sheet2 and sheet3

Comment: =IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet1!A:B,1,FALSE)),IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A1,‌​Sheet2!A:A,1,FALSE))‌​,IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A1,‌​Sheet3!A:A,2,FALSE))‌​,"Invalid Data", "Sheet 3"),"Sheet2"),"Sheet1")    this formula working .... but i dont want to look in sheet1 ... am trying to modify ... getting error

Comment: am finding sheet1 a1 to a5 values into sheet2 and sheet3 a:a is there or not in sheet2 if found comment need as sheet2 if not it has to loop sheet3 a:a range if found sheet3 if not comment as invalid ( only three sheet i have in workbook)

Comment: i really appreciate your help and looking this last doubt how to modify

Comment: =IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!A:A,1,FALSE)),IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet3!A:A,2,FALSE)),"Invalid Data", "Sheet 2"),"Sheet1")

Comment: Modified succefully

Comment: Thank you so much ..... i really appreciate your tips .... initially felt very hard ... ( You are Master)

Comment: Sub Vlookup_3comments()

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    'Selecting output result cell
    Range("B1").Select
    'apply formula with comments ( it has find in sheet2 and sheet3 , if not found in both comment as invalid data)
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(RC[-1],Sheet2!C[-1],1,FALSE)),IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(RC[-1],Sheet3!C[-1],1,FALSE)),""Invalid Data"", ""Sheet 3""),""Sheet2"")"

    LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("B1").AutoFill Destination:=Range("B1:B" & LastRow)
    
End Sub

Comment: applied VBA code , Code working fine any suggestions welcome